# dplyr: sum inside consecutive mutate

Tags: r, sum, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
tib <- tibble(a = c(1,2,3))
```

The following work as expected:

```
tib %>% mutate(b = a^2, c = sqrt(b))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1
2     2     4     2
3     3     9     3

tib %>% mutate(b = a^2, c = sum(a))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     6
2     2     4     6
3     3     9     6

tib %>% mutate(b = a^2) %>% mutate(c = sum(b))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1    14
2     2     4    14
3     3     9    14
```

The following does not:

```
tib %>% mutate(b = a^2, c = sum(b))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a     b             c
  <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>
1     1     1 1.482197e-323
2     2     4 1.482197e-323
3     3     9 1.482197e-323
```

I would expect the result in column c to be the same as above, 14 everywhere.
Any insight about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Works as expected for me

Comment: @Sotos And what version you use? It doesn't work for me with `dplyr 0.7.0`. This look likes the bug for me.

Comment: Looks like a hybrid-eval bug; `tibble(a = c(1,2,3), b = a^2, c = sum(b))` and `tib %>% mutate(b = a^2, c = sum(.data$b))` work as expected.

Comment: Hm... I m on `0.5.0`

Comment: I've checked with `0.5.0`. Works fine. That's a bug in `0.7.0`. I will fill the issue on Github.

Comment: @Sotos I use `dplyr 0.7.0` as well.

Comment: @Habert yes. Apparently it's a bug. It has been filed.

Comment: This [has already been fixed](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2842) in the dev version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have checked with both `dplyr` versions: it's looks like a bug in new `tidyeval` engine. I have filed the bug on [Github](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2883).

---

Update:

This is now fixed. [`Issue`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2842#event-1125218852). The new version of `dplyr` 0.7.1 and above doesn't have this issue anymore.

Comment: Thanks for doing that.